# Submit Dynamically Generated From in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have the following form generated dynamically from JavaScript based on user's action:

```
<form id="editBookForm" onsubmit="editBookData()">
   <input type="text" name="isbn" placeholder="ISBN"  required />
   <input type="text" name="book" placeholder="Book..."  required />
   <button class ="btn">Update!</button>
</form>
```

The editBookData function is:

```
function editBookData(data) {
    console.log(data)
   //Some other work
}
```

How can I prevent default submission behavior and pass the form data so that I can access the form data in the **editBookData()** function?

No Jquery please! Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Take the `event` as a parameter to your function and call `.preventDefault()` on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) method to the stop `form` from reloading and use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method to get the form input text `values` in your function

**Live Demo:** (No jQuery)

```js
function editBookData(e) {
  e.preventDefault() //prevent default behaviour 
  //get input value
  let isbn = document.querySelector('input[name="isbn"]').value
  let book = document.querySelector('input[name="book"]').value
  console.log(isbn, book)
  //Do Some other work with values
}
```

```html
<form id="editBookForm" onsubmit="editBookData(event)">
  <input type="text" name="isbn" placeholder="ISBN" required />
  <input type="text" name="book" placeholder="Book..." required />
  <button class="btn">Update!</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you @AlwaysHelping. Appreciate it. :)

Comment: @hadira2145 Glad to help. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the submission of the form and use the `FormData` Web API to generating a form dynamically.

[Event.preventDefault reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

[FormData API on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)

```js
function editBookData(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let editBookForm = document.getElementById('editBookForm');
  let formData = new FormData(editBookForm);
  for (item of formData.values()) {
    console.log(item);
  }
  // .... other things to do
}
```

```html
<form id="editBookForm" onsubmit="editBookData(event)">
      <input type="text" name="isbn" placeholder="ISBN" required />
      <input type="text" name="book" placeholder="Book..." required />
      <button class="btn">Update!</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Not ideal !! How would you **differentiate** which text `value` is what if you use `formData` here ? Because `item` will show both values here. No point using formData here if there are two values only.

Comment: FormDatay has other methods like `FormData.get(name)`. You can use it to get each input value by its name attribute.